# About samba sharing in 12.4 ubuntu server

Tags: file-sharing

I have created a folder in samba sharing in that I have created spread sheet an I gave full permission to that folder and file in command line my users are in workgroup they cannot access that file at the same time if one had had open that file to edit in the sense another user can only able to read that file cannot edit that file it shows as " you can only read because another user is using" how to solve this problem ? users have to access that file at one time from samba sharing

Answer (score 1):

This is not a restriction of Samba or file permissions, it's due to the spreadsheet software. The application doesn't allow simultaneous editing and locks the spreadsheet to read-only mode after it has been opened by the first user. The solution depends on the application you use. For example, Excel has limited sharing capabilities which can be found in `Tools -> Share Workbook...`. More information on Excel sharing can be found on the [Office](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/overview-of-sharing-and-collaborating-on-excel-data-HA010089896.aspx#BM5) site. For other applications, see the documentation of the application.